# Fullcalendar v4: addEvent() not working in custom view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I am using fullcalendar v4 (https://fullcalendar.io/) and I am trying to refresh the dropped event in a custom view 'timeGridSixMonth'.

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                plugins: [ 'bootstrap', 'interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
                defaultView: 'timeGridSixMonth',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'timeGridSixMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listSixMonth'
                },
                buttonText: {
                    timeGridSixMonth: '6 Month',
                    listSixMonth: 'List 6 Month'
                },
                views: {
                        timeGridSixMonth: {
                        type: 'dayGrid',
                        duration: { month: 6 },
                        titleFormat: { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' },
                    },
                        listSixMonth: {
                        type: 'listMonth',
                        duration: { month: 6 },
                        titleFormat: { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' } 
                    }
},
```

.....

```
drop: function(info) {

                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });

                console.log(info);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/plan',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        'title':          info.jsEvent.explicitOriginalTarget.textContent
                        'item_id':        $('#item_id').children("option:selected"). val(),
                        'start':          start,
                        'end':            end,
                        'users_id':{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth ::user() -> id }},
                     },
                    success: function (response) {

                        console.log(response);
                        calendar.addEvent({
                            title:  response.data.title,
                            start:  response.data.start,
                            end:    response.data.end,
                            allDay: false,
                            id:     response.data.id,
                        });
                        displayMessage('gespeichert.');
                    }
                });
            },
```

> The response is:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "Fach": "Rhetorik",
    "faecher_id": 22,
    "dozenten_id": 112,
    "schulungsorte_id": 18,
    "Beginn": "2020-10-29T16:00:00.000000Z",
    "Ende": "2020-10-29T20:00:00.000000Z",
    "kurstermine_id": "14,17,7,21",
    "users_id": 3,
    "updated_at": "2020-04-01T16:15:34.000000Z",
    "created_at": "2020-04-01T16:15:34.000000Z",
    "id": 26,
    "title": "Rhetorik\n        Mr. Miller",
    "start": "2020-10-29T16:00:00.000000Z",
    "end": "2020-10-29T20:00:00.000000Z"
  },
  "message": "stored."
}
```

In the custom view an event without id is created and addEvent() doesn't work.

In standard views i get a duplicate event without id.

Do you guess why?

Comment: "doesn't work" means what? You get an error? Or some other unexpected result? if you change the view to a standard one afterwards, can you then see the event? Does it exist in your database? It's unclear precisely how the view type can be affecting it, or what "an event without id is created" means...ID from where? You mean no ID comes from the database into `response.data.id` or something? You need to clarify the whole situation more, please.

Comment: ok. Do you realise you are creating **two** events? First the one which is dropped, and then another one which is added via `addEvent()`? Is that the intention?

Comment: Also can you please show the code where you define and populate the draggable external events, so that I know precisely what you are dropping onto the calendar?

Comment: No error. The event is stored in the datebase properly,  `response.data.id` comes back, but the element dropped has no id. (if i click on the event 'eventClick: function(info) {   alert(info.event.id);} ' shows 'undefined'.

So i tried to add the event with the addEvent() method, this is shown in standard views, but not in the custom view 'timeGridSixMonth'.
In standard views i have two events: One from addEvent(9 and another without id from the 'drop:'
Sorry for my unprecise description.
Thanx for your help.

Comment: The element dropped will not have any ID, if you didn't assign it one. That's not surprising, unless you think it should? If so, where from? That's why I asked to see how you are creating the draggable events. Anyway to try and understand why the result of addEvent() might not show in your custom view, I first need to see the event data. if you could please add `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` in your "success" callback, and then post the result of that into your question it would be very helpful.

Comment: The draggable external event is:
                            @foreach($items as $item)
                                <button class='fc-event' data-event='{{ $item->id  }}' style="margin: 5px; width: 95%;">{{ $item->title }}</button>
                            @endforeach

`            new Draggable(containerEl, {
                itemSelector: '.fc-event',
                eventData: function(eventEl) {
                    return {
                        title: eventEl.innerText
                    };
                }
            });`

Comment: Code is not very readable when placed in the comments. As I said, please add it to your question. There is an "edit" button just under the blue "javascript" tag at the bottom of your post.

Comment: But I can see enough from that to know that your dropped elements will never have an ID (except for an internal one that fullCalendar will assign it it, but that's not much use to you). I also still don't understand why you want there to be two events? Would it not be better to update the dropped one, instead of making a duplicate?

Comment: You can access the dropped event's data through the `eventReceive` callback (instead of `drop`). See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(response)) gives:
`{"success":true,"data":{"title":"Zeitmanagement","faecher_id":26,"dozenten_id":112,"schulungsorte_id":18,"Beginn":"2020-11-17T16:00:00.000000Z","Ende":"2020-11-17T20:00:00.000000Z","kurstermine_id":"14,17,7,21","users_id":3,"updated_at":"2020-04-01T16:03:33.000000Z","created_at":"2020-04-01T16:03:33.000000Z","id":22,"title":"Zeitmanagement\n        John Doo"},"message":"stored"} 18:721:37`

Comment: Once again: please add your extra code and data to your **question**. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60969925/edit

Comment: But again I can see a problem. `response.data.start` and `response.data.end` do not exist in that JSON. So your start and end dates of your new event would be undefined. And `title` is duplicated! This should not happen if you serialise your JSON properly.

Comment: Anyhow like I said it's really not clear why you are duplicating your events, when you could just update the properties of the event which was dropped, to add the ID.

Comment: How can i get the object of the dropped event ?

`success: function (response) {

console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
info.event.setProp('title', response.data.title);
info.event.setProp('id', response.data.id);
}`


TypeError: info.event is undefined

Comment: See my comment above about `eventReceive`

Comment: Now it works, thank you very much.
drop: was the wrong attempt, eventReceive did it.

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED:

I used eventReceive instead of drop:

```
eventReceive: function(info) {

       console.log('eventReceive', info);

       var starttime   = moment(info.event._instance.range.start).utcOffset(0).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
       var endtime     = moment(info.event._instance.range.start).utcOffset(0).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

                        $.ajaxSetup({
                            headers: {
                                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                            }
                        });

                        console.log(info);

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/api/plan',
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {
                                'title':            info.draggedEl.innerText,
                                'item_id':      info.draggedEl.dataset.event,
                                'start':          starttime,
                                'end':            endtime,
                                'users_id':{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth ::user() -> id }},
                            },
                            success: function (response) {

                                console.log(response);
                                info.event.setProp('title', response.data.title);
                                info.event.setProp('id', response.data.id);
                                info.event.setProp('start', response.data.start);
                                info.event.setProp('end', response.data.end);
                            }
                        });
                    },
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need to do setProp on the title, start and end properties. They should already be correct - unless your server is changing them before it sends the response back? I think you would only need to run setProp to set the ID, really.

Comment: I use two fields in the database and merge the output to title to display the information.
Thanx for your help, your hints helped me a lot.